# Prove that $e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{2}}+e^{x-\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^x-x \ge0$，where $x\leq0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

> Prove that $$e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{2}}+e^{x-\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^x-x \ge0$$
> where $x\leq0$.

First I tried to find the derivative , but it is hard to find the sign of it.
I also found that when $x$ is roughly smaller than $-2$ , $-2e^x-x \ge 0$ is easy to prove.
So the question is how to prove it when $x$ is near 0, I tried $e^x \ge x+1$ , failed totally.

Wish someone could help and thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by $2x - x^2/2$? is it $\frac{2x-x^2}{2}$ or $2x - \frac{x^2}{2}$

Comment: the latter. sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: No worries. I am trying to solve it, if I will be able to solve it, I will provide my solution\

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We divide both sides of
$$e^{2x-\frac{x^2}{2}}+e^{x-\frac{x^2}{2}}-2e^x-x \ge0$$
by $e^x$ and we replace $x$ with $-x$. Then we have to show that for $x\geq 0$
$$e^{-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}-2+xe^{x}\geq 0.$$
By AM-GM inequality $e^{-x-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\geq 2e^{-\frac{x+x^{2}}{2}}$, so it suffices to prove that
$$2e^{-\frac{x+x^{2}}{2}}-2+xe^{x}\geq 0.$$
Moreover $e^t\geq 1+t$ implies that it remains to show
$$2\left(1-\frac{x+x^{2}}{2}\right)-2+xe^{x}\geq 0,$$
that is
$$-x-x^{2}+xe^{x}=x(-1-x+e^{x})\geq 0$$
which trivially holds for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Excellent!Thank you most sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at typing. I write on a paper.[image]

Comment: Learn [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/876009) how to write maths in this website